# True/False depending on screen size dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm following a guide that allows Google Map screen to disable scrolling depending on the screen size. The only part i'm struggling is to write a code that dynamically changes the True/False value when i resize the screen manually.

This is the website that I followed the instruction but I can't seem to write the correct syntax code to produce the dynamic true false value depending on the screen size https://coderwall.com/p/pgm8xa/disable-google-maps-scrolling-on-mobile-layout

Part of the code that i need to use:

```
$(window).resize()
```

And then:

```
setOptions()
```

So I'm struggling to combine them together.

I have tried something like this:

```
var dragging = $(window).width(function resize() {
    if (dragging > 560) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would "dragging" have both a boolean and numeric value (550)?

Comment: my impression is that if val is true or false it will pass one of them to dragging? depending on the condition which in this case is the screen size is more 560 then true, else false

Comment: You could replace your function core with:  return (dragging > 560);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked to is lacking important information as it fails to mention that `$` is (presumably) [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). But you don't need jQuery at all.
What you can use instead is the [`MediaQueryList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList). It is similar to media queries in CSS, but it is a JavaScript API.

The following is an untested example of how you might use it with a [`MediaQueryList` event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener). It sets the initial value and listens to changes to your media query with a handler that uses [setOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setOptions) from the Google Maps API.

```
var mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 560px)');
var isDraggable = mql.matches;

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    draggable: isDraggable
  });
}

function mqChange(e) {
  map.setOptions({draggable: !!e.matches});
}

mql.addListener(mqChange);
```

Comment: hm getting: main.js:607 Uncaught TypeError: map.setOptions is not a function
    at MediaQueryList.mqChange

Comment: Did you initialize Google Maps as per their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)? Can you log `map` before `map.setOptions` is called?

Comment: yep it's working now something is going wrong with what starts so i will fix it. but yep this worked thanks

Comment: Found the issue i was declaring `var map = ...` inside `function initMap()`, basically writing `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')`

Answer (score 1):

You could add an event listener to the resize event and set a value of your variable whenever the size of the window is changed:

```
var dragging = false;
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  dragging = window.innerWidth > 560;
});
```

Since you mentioned that you want to disable scrolling when the windows size extends a certain value, it might be easier to just do this. If you try it you can see in the console that the value changes whenever you resize your window):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  console.log(window.innerWidth);
  if (window.innerWidth > 560) {
    // disable scrolling or do whatever you want to do
  }
});
```

BTW, in your code you do this:

```
 if (dragging > 560) {
     return true;
 } else {
     return false;
 }
```

You can simplify this to:

```
return dragging > 560
```

Which is exactly the same.

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: the simplify is good, but in this case i'm still looking when i resize screen myself on desktop for it to disable scroll on small screen.

Comment: when i drag window screen and resize it

Comment: I adjusted the answer, please try and use the code and you can see in the console that it does work :)

Comment: yep it does work so i just need to work out to change these values to true and false and then apply them to google map thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the width and height on a resize of the screen.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $windowHeight = $(window).height();
    // run other functions or code
});
```

But, if you want to only show/hide a html element based on the screen size, you can also use plain html/css.

```
<div id="maps"></div>
```

Css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 560px) {
    #maps {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: no no, i don't need to hide elements, i need to disable scroll functionality depending on screen size.

Comment: In that case just use CSS. Media queries and `overflow: hidden` should work

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [matchMedia function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener) to run a callback whenever the media query status is changing

```
var mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 700px)');

function mediaHandler(e) {
   if (e.matches) {
      /* the viewport is more than 700 pixels wide */
   } else {
      /* the viewport is 700 pixels wide or less */
   }
}

mql.addListener(mediaHandler);
```